# How do I read a .txt file into a 2D array in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, row, filereader, columnsorting

I can't figure out what's wrong with my program. I want to read a .txt file named "salesReport" into a 2D array, but it only reads one line.

The 2D array has 10 rows and 12 columns, and I also need help arranging the array, when it is printed, to be in 10 rows and 12 columns with 3 spaces in between.

**MY TEXT FILE**

```
31
74
22
05
61
84
14
86
55
22
09
81
83
91
23
49
96
45
41
45
26
77
77
19
84
03
65
91
31
62
73
92
49
93
43
36
69
05
96
54
59
84
14
16
49
35
28
51
60
98
42
61
59
40
01
98
85
80
90
20
22
43
54
71
47
35
81
86
04
61
60
34
35
08
14
44
90
51
27
50
73
53
75
52
19
72
86
41
17
04
46
11
45
25
21
66
96
48
98
06
61
38
11
96
19
63
32
03
11
30
84
80
17
73
90
40
69
55
90
92
```

**MY CODE**

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Needed for the Scanner class
import java.io.*;  // Needed for the File class

public class salesReport
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
     
   // Create a Scanner object to read input.
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      int[] A;
      int[][] B;
      int i=11,j=13;
      
      A = arrayFile(121);
      
      System.out.println(A);
      
      B = showArray(i,j,A);
     
   }
   
   public static int[] arrayFile(int a) throws IOException
   {
   // Create a Scanner object to read input.
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      int A[];
      A = new int[a];
   
      System.out.print("Enter the filename: ");
      String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
   
      File file = new File(filename);
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
      
      int i=0;
   
      while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
      {
         i++;
         A[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
      }
      return A;
   }
   
   public static int[][] showArray(int i,int j,int[] C) throws IOException
   {
   // Create a Scanner object to read input.
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      int[][] A;
      
      A = new int[i][j];
      
      for (int row = 0;row < A.length;row++)
      {
         for (int col = 0;col < A[row].length;col++)
         {
            System.out.print(A[row][col] + " ");
            System.out.println();
         }       
      }
      return A;
   }
    
}
```

Comment: What does the three spaces in between mean for your print requirement?

Comment: @RichardKYu
Something like this

`
System.out.printf("%-3d",A[i]);
`

Comment: Are we allowed to use Streams API?

Comment: @RichardKYu
No, I am not allowed to use Streams API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt. I put three spaces between each element in a row and three spaces between the columns.

**Edit:** Changed print method to avoid using Streams API.

```
// Needed for the File class
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for the Scanner class

public class Read2D {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int rows = 10;
        int columns = 12;

        int[] arr = arrayFile(rows * columns);
    
        int[][] md_arr = new int[rows][columns];

        for(int r=0; r < rows; r++) {
            for(int c=0; c<columns; c++) {
            md_arr[r][c] = arr[r*c+c];
            }
        }
    
        showArray(md_arr);

    }

    public static int[] arrayFile(int a) throws IOException {
        // Create a Scanner object to read input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int A[];
        A = new int[a];

        System.out.print("Enter the filename: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.close();

        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        int i = 0;

        while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
            A[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        inputFile.close();

        return A;
    }

    public static void showArray(int[][] C) {
        for(int r=0; r < C.length; r++) {
            for(int c=0; c<C[r].length; c++) {
                System.out.print(C[r][c]+"   ");
            }
                System.out.print("\n\n\n");
        }
    
    }

}
```

Output:

```
31   74   22   5   61   84   14   86   55   22   9   81   


31   22   61   14   55   9   83   23   96   41   26   77   


31   5   14   22   83   49   41   77   84   91   73   93   


31   61   55   83   96   26   84   31   49   69   59   49   


31   84   9   49   26   3   73   36   59   35   42   98   


31   14   83   41   84   73   69   14   60   1   22   81   


31   86   23   77   31   36   14   98   85   71   60   51   


31   55   96   84   49   59   60   85   47   35   73   17   


31   22   41   91   69   35   1   71   35   53   46   6   


31   9   26   73   59   42   22   60   73   46   61   84
```